# 2006/2007 iMac SSD fresh OS X installation

Tags: macos, mac, ssd, imac

Today I replaced the 2x512MB sticks with 2x2GB sticks of DDR2 RAM and replaced the crumby slow 250GB hard drive with a 90GB Muskin SSD. We ran out of time because the OS X installation DVD only reliably booted once. So...

1. What do I have to do (e.g. hold a specific key down) after turning on the iMac with the installation DVD in the drive?
2. Will the startup disk utility show the SSD even if the drives to install won't? e.g. I have no problem formatting the SSD to Journal or whatever the Apple disk format is. I only spotted the file menu at the top after deciding to temporarily install to the external drive they had, though I'm not entirely sure it was there before I clicked the last button to have it install.

So just a recap: I have a blank SSD hard drive installed to a white 2006/2007 iMac and I'm trying to install OS X from the DVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mac should automatically boot of off the DVD. You can then follow the steps to install OSX (including formatting the drive).

If it does not automatically boot, hold down the <kbd>c</kbd> key while booting.

[Apple Support doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Note that the maximum version you can install on a 2006 iMac is 10.7.5